# Issue with Python logging using JSON output

Tags: python, json, logging

I am using the below Python script to output the logs as JSON.
Python Script Used

```html
import json
import logging
import time
import random
from datetime import date, datetime
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger


def setup_logging(log_level):
    logger = logging.getLogger()

    logger.setLevel(log_level)
    json_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter(
        fmt='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s'
    )
    json_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(json_handler)


setup_logging(logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger()

# Start time
StartTime = datetime.now()

# Sample Log Data
message_dictionary = {
    'ApplicationName': 'Application ABC',
    'StartTime': StartTime,
}

logger.info(message_dictionary)
```

However, in the output logs, the key "message" is showing as null which is followed by the Log output (see below).

```
{
"asctime": "2022-06-29 12:08:27,059",
"levelname": "INFO",
"name": "root",
"message": null,
"ApplicationName": "Application ABC",
"StartTime": "2022-06-29T12:08:27.059175"
```

}

Any suggestions on what may be causing the "message" to be null in the above log output?

How do I possibly output something like below in my log output ?

```
{
"asctime": "2022-06-29 12:08:27,059",
"levelname": "INFO",
"name": "root",
"message": [{
    "ApplicationName": "Application ABC",
    "StartTime": "2022-06-29T12:08:27.059175"
}]
```

}

Comment: The log message should be a string. Additional data should be given as the `extra` argument.

Comment: Hi @KlausD. , Do you have an example on how to pass the additional data as the extra argument?

Comment: If I do the below conversion - 
json_message = json.dumps(message_dictionary, default=str)
logger.info(json_message) 

The output shows as below with escape characters added.  
{"asctime": "2022-06-29 13:03:42,616", "levelname": "INFO", "name": "root", "message": "{\"SourceSystem\": \"PASX\", \"ExtractName\": \"textActivity\", \"StartTime\": \"2022-06-29 10:15:38.656735\", \"EndTime\": \"2022-06-29 10:15:40.761323\", \"NumOfRecordsRead\": 61589}"}

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html → Search the page  for "extra".